# How can I get a CSS animation to work in reverse?

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation, css-animations

I am trying to animate my menu. The menu open animation works fine, but I can't get the menu close animation to work.

The menu opens fine, but I don't know how to make it close with the MenuClose settings.

```js
function showMenu() {
  const el = document.getElementById("MenuContainer");
  el.classList.toggle('MenuOpen');
}
```

```css
#MenuContainer {
  height: 0px;
  left: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 5px 0px 0px 0px;
  position: relative;
  top: 20px;
  width: 0px;
}

.MenuOpen {
  animation-direction: normal;
  animation-duration: 4s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-name: Menu;
}

.MenuClose {
  animation-direction: reverse;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-name: Menu;
}

@keyframes Menu {
  from {
    height: 0px;
    width: 0px;
  }
  to {
    height: 100px;
    width: 300px;
  }
}
```

```html
<input id="MenuButton" type="button" value="Menu" onclick="showMenu();" title="Menu" />
<div id="MenuContainer"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 main points:

- you toggle MenuOpen with... nothing, it puts menuopen and remove it
- better to have open animation and close animation, eas

```js
function showMenu() {
  const el = document.getElementById("MenuContainer");
  if (el.classList.contains('MenuOpen')) {
    el.classList.add('MenuClose');
    el.classList.remove('MenuOpen');
  } else {
    el.classList.add('MenuOpen');
    el.classList.remove('MenuClose');
  }
}
```

```css
#MenuContainer {
  height: 0px;
  left: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 5px 0px 0px 0px;
  position: relative;
  top: 20px;
  width: 0px;
  background-color: #3388ff;
}

.MenuOpen {
  animation-duration: 4s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-name: MenuOpen;
}

.MenuClose {
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-name: MenuClose;
}

@keyframes MenuOpen {
  from {
    height: 0px;
    width: 0px;
  }
  to {
    height: 100px;
    width: 300px;
  }
}

@keyframes MenuClose {
  from {
    height: 100px;
    width: 300px;
  }
  to {
    height: 0px;
    width: 0px;
  }
}
```

```html
<input id="MenuButton" type="button" value="Menu" onclick="showMenu();" title="Menu" />
<div id="MenuContainer"></div>
```

ier to control

Answer (score 0):

You can use if else statement and replace function to toggle the open close animation.

```
//Get the menu container
const el = document.getElementById("MenuContainer");

// Function to toggle the menu open/close animation
function showMenu() {
  // Check if the menu container has the 'MenuOpen' class
  if (el.classList.contains('MenuOpen')) {
    // Replace the 'MenuOpen' class with 'MenuClose'
    el.classList.replace('MenuOpen', 'MenuClose');
  } else {
    // Add the 'MenuOpen' class to the menu container
    el.classList.add('MenuOpen');
  }
}
```

Hope this will help. This is just one solution of many ways.

Comment: You should copy the demo down here and show your solution live.